# How to iterate over all DbSet in a generic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, iteration

(I'm using EF6 here)
Say I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyContext<T> : DbContext
```

and let's put it to use:

```
public class MyTestContext : MyContext<MyTestContext>
{
    public DbSet<Object1> Object1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Object2> Object2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, say I want to iterate over all the DbSets in MyTestContext, in my abstract class.  Seems this would work (this is in a method in my abstract class):

```
var dbSetProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<>));
```

Yet I get "Enumeration yielded no results".

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

*edit* Note - I don't expect to know the generic type arguments up front - I'm actually looking to determine what Types are in each of the DbSets.

Comment: Properties are not of type DbSet<>, their generic definition is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So a `Foo<T>` isn't of type `Foo<>`. You need to get the generic type definition of your `Foo<T>`s and compare those.

```
var dbSetProperties = typeof(MyTestContext)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>));
```

Comment: Ha, seems so obvious in retrospect.  Thank you, that did it.  I'll give you the answer in... ah.. 6 minutes :)